# Scraping Javascript in R with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm attempting to scrape the [Washington Post's database on police shootings](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/national/police-shootings/). Since it's not html I can't use `rvest`, so instead I used [RSelenium](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RSelenium/) and [phantomjs](https://phantomjs.org).

```
library(RSelenium)

checkForServer()
startServer()

eCap <- list(phantomjs.binary.path = "C:/Program Files/Chrome Driver/phantomjs.exe")
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", extraCapabilities = eCap)

remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("http://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/national/police-shootings/")
```

Upon inspecting the source, it's apparent the items I'm interested in have the following `id` and `class`

```
<div id="js-list-690" class="listWrapper cf">
```

or in Chrome:

[image: screenshot of the relevant item's source in Chrome]

I can access the text of the individual item:

```
remDr$findElement("css", "#js-list-691")$getElementText()
```

returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "An unidentified person, a 47-year-old Hispanic man, was shocked with a stun gun and shot on July 30, 2015, in Whittier, Calif. Los Angeles County deputies were investigating a domestic disturbance when he threatened the officers and struck one of them with a metal rod.\nMALEDEADLY WEAPONHISPANIC45 TO 54\nCBS Los AngelesWhittier Daily News"}
```

But if I want to get a list of all these items:

```
remDr$findElements("class name", "listWrapper cf")
```

results in an error.

How do I

1. Get a list of all the elements which share this `listWrapper cf` class?
2. Return a list of the text associated with each element?

Comment: Why don't you just use the data directly from https://js.washingtonpost.com/graphics/policeshootings/policeshootings.json?d14385542 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'd be *way* easier to just use the JSON data directly (use the "Developer Tools" in almost any modern browser to track the URLs loaded...this didn't take long to find in that list):

```
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://js.washingtonpost.com/graphics/policeshootings/policeshootings.json?d14385542"

shootings <- fromJSON(url)

dplyr::glimpse(shootings)

## Observations: 564
## Variables:
## $ id                 (int) 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, ...
## $ date               (chr) "2015-01-02", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "...
## $ description        (chr) "Elliot, who was on medication for depressi...
## $ blurb              (chr) "a 53-year-old man of Asian heritage armed ...
## $ name               (chr) "Tim Elliot", "Lewis Lee Lembke", "John Pau...
## $ age                (int) 53, 47, 23, 32, 39, 18, 22, 35, 34, 47, 25,...
## $ gender             (chr) "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F"...
## $ race               (chr) "A", "W", "H", "W", "H", "W", "H", "W", "W"...
## $ armed              (chr) "gun", "gun", "unarmed", "toy weapon", "nai...
## $ city               (chr) "Shelton", "Aloha", "Wichita", "San Francis...
## $ state              (chr) "WA", "OR", "KS", "CA", "CO", "OK", "AZ", "...
## $ address            (chr) "600 block of E. Island Lake Drive", "4519 ...
## $ lat                (dbl) 47.24683, 45.48620, 37.69477, 37.76291, 40....
## $ lon                (dbl) -123.12159, -122.89128, -97.28055, -122.422...
## $ is_geocoding_exact (lgl) TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, T...
## $ mental             (lgl) TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FAL...
## $ sources            (list) http://kbkw.com/local-news/329755, http://...
## $ photos             (list) NULL, NULL, 107, , , , //img.washingtonpos...
## $ videos             (list) NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ...
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr--thanks! this is fantastic. I'll keep the question open to see if I can find a more general solution using Selenium, but this definitely resolves this challenge.

Comment: Hi, this answers looks like it might be a big help to my own projects. Can you explain a bit more the part _"use the "Developer Tools" in almost any modern browser to track the URLs loaded"_ or point me towards an online guide or tutorial please?

Comment: @user3198404 Not an expert here but... Using Chrome: _Right-click_ > _Inspect_; navigate to _Network_ tab >  type in _.json_ > Search > Refresh Site (to catch calls made prior)

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thanks!