# How do I scrape / automatically download PDF files from a document search web interface in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, text, nlp, tidyr

I am using the R programming language for NLP (natural language process) analysis - for this, I need to "webscrape" publicly available information on the internet.

Recently, I learned how to "webscrape" a single pdf file from the website I am using :

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidytext)
library(textrank)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

#this is an example of a single pdf
url <- "https://www.canlii.org/en/ns/nswcat/doc/2013/2013canlii47876/2013canlii47876.pdf"

article <- pdf_text(url)
article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)


article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)


article_words <- article_words %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")

#this final command can take some time to run
article_summary <- textrank_sentences(data = article_sentences, terminology = article_words)

#Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979242/r-error-in-textrank-sentencesdata-article-sentences-terminology-article-w  ,  https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/tidy-text-summarization-using-textrank/
```

The above code works fine if you want to manually access a single website and then "webscrape" this website. Now, I want to try and automatically download 10 such articles at the same time, without manually visiting each page. For instance, suppose I want to download the first 10 pdf's from this website: https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=dog%20toronto

I think I found the following website which discusses how to do something similar (I adapted the code for my example): https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-downloading-and-storing-pdfs-in-r-367a0a6d9199

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

page <- read_html("https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=dog%20toronto ")

raw_list <- page %>% 
    html_nodes("a") %>%  
    html_attr("href") %>% 
    str_subset("\\.pdf") %>% 
    str_c("https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=dog", .) 
    map(read_html) %>% 
    map(html_node, "#raw-url") %>% 
    map(html_attr, "href") %>% 
    str_c("https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=dog", .) %>% 
    walk2(., basename(.), download.file, mode = "wb")
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in .f(.x[[1L]], .y[[1L]], ...) : scheme not supported in URL 'NA'
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Is it possible to download the first 10 pdf files that appear on this website and save them individually in R as "pdf1", "pdf2", ... "pdf9", "pdf10"?

Thanks

Comment: If I run everything up to the last `walk2` command, your code returns just `NA`. You can't pass `NA` to `download.file()` because that's not a valid URL. The page you are trying to work with generates all its data via javascript. You cannot use `rvest` with pages that require javascript. You'll need to use something like [Rseleniun](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I know very little about Rseleniun - I will start reading right now!

Comment: Can it be done with this package? https://github.com/salimk/Rcrawler

Answer (score 1):

I see some people suggesting that you use `rselenium`, which is a way to
simulate browser actions, so that the web server renders the page as
if a human was visiting the site. From my experience it is almost never
necessary to go down that route. The javascript part of the website is
interacting with an API and we can utilize that to circumvent the Javascript
part and get the raw json data directly. In Firefox (and Chrome is similar in that regard I
assume) you can right-click on the website and select “Inspect Element (Q)”,
go to the “Network” tab and click on reload. You’ll see that each request
the browser makes to the webserver is being listed after a few seconds or less.
We are interested in the ones that have the “Type” `json`.
When you right click on an entry you can select “Open in New Tab”. One of the
requests that returns json has the following URL attached to it https://www.canlii.org/en/search/ajaxSearch.do?type=decision&text=dogs%20toronto&page=1
Opening that URL in Firefox gets you to a GUI that lets you explore the
json data structure and you’ll see that there is a “results” entry which
contains the data for the 25 first results of your search. Each one has a
“path” entry, that leads to the page that will display the embedded PDF.
It turns out that if you replace the “.html” part with “.pdf” that path
leads directly to the PDF file. The code below utilizes all this information.

```r
library(tidyverse) # tidyverse for the pipe and for `purrr::map*()` functions.
library(httr) # this should already be installed on your machine as `rvest` builds on it
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 20.09.0
library(tidytext)
library(textrank)

base_url <- "https://www.canlii.org"

json_url_search_p1 <-
  "https://www.canlii.org/en/search/ajaxSearch.do?type=decision&text=dogs%20toronto&page=1"
```

This downloads the json for page 1 / results 1 to 25

```r
results_p1 <-
  GET(json_url_search_p1, encode = "json") %>%
  content()
```

For each result we extract the path only.

```r
result_html_paths_p1 <-
  map_chr(results_p1$results,
          ~ .$path)
```

We replace “.html” with “.pdf”, combine the base URL with the path to
generate the full URLs pointing to the PDFs. Last we pipe it into `purrr::map()`
and `pdftools::pdf_text` in order to extract the text from all 25 PDFs.

```r
pdf_texts_p1 <-
  gsub(".html$", ".pdf", result_html_paths_p1) %>%
  paste0(base_url, .) %>%
  map(pdf_text)
```

If you want to do this for more than just the first page you might want to
wrap the above code in a function that lets you switch out the “&page=”
parameter. You could also make the “&text=” parameter an argument of the
function in order to automatically scrape results for other searches.

For the remaining part of the task we can build on the code you already have.
We make it a function that can be applied to any article and apply that function
to each PDF text again using `purrr::map()`.

```r
extract_article_summary <-
  function(article) {
    article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
      unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
      mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
      select(sentence_id, sentence)
    
    
    article_words <- article_sentences %>%
      unnest_tokens(word, sentence)
    
    
    article_words <- article_words %>%
      anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")
    
    textrank_sentences(data = article_sentences, terminology = article_words)
  }
```

This now will take a real long time!

```r
article_summaries_p1 <- 
  map(pdf_texts_p1, extract_article_summary)
```

Alternatively you could use `furrr::future_map()` instead to utilize all the CPU
cores in your machine and speed up the process.

```r
library(furrr) # make sure the package is installed first
plan(multisession)
article_summaries_p1 <- 
  future_map(pdf_texts_p1, extract_article_summary)
```

## Disclaimer

The code in the answer above is for educational purposes only. As many websites do, this service restricts automated access to its contents. The [robots.txt](https://www.canlii.org/robots.txt) explicitly disallows the `/search` path from being accessed by bots. It is therefore recommended to get in contact with the site owner before downloading big amounts of data. canlii offers API access on an individual request basis, see [documentation here](https://github.com/canlii/API_documentation/blob/master/EN.md). This would be the correct and safest way to access their data.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I just launched the code right now and waiting to see what happens (the code is still running)! it seems that "pdf_texts_p1" contains the text containing to the first 25 articles. Is there a way to isolate the text from each article into a separate R object? E.g. "p1" contains all the text for the first article, "p2" contains all the text for the second article?

Comment: You can do that with `list2env()`, but you'd have to name the list first with something like `names(pdf_texts_p1) <- paste0("pdf", 1:25)` and then do `list2env(pdf_texts_p1, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. I would not recommend doing that though. In most cases it is better to keep the data in a list and iterate through it with something like `purrr::map()` or `base::lapply()`.

Comment: Sure, a loop works for that. Alternatively use `purrr::map()` for that as well. After wrapping the code in a function, maybe named `download_results_page()`, that takes the page as an argument you could just do `map(1:20, download_results_page)` to get the texts from all PDF on the pages 1 to 20.

Comment: I think you are right, I just assumed this was public data that can be scraped. maybe its better to get in contact with the site owners before webscraping

Comment: I don't hink the question needs to be deleted, but if you want to access more than the first page, you should get in contact with them first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230906/discussion-between-noob-and-till).